# How do I get the queue time of a completed build in TFS using the API?

Tags: tfs

I would like to check how long gated check-in builds are waiting in the queue. However, I cannot find the API function to get this information.

How can I do it?

**EDIT 1**

Please, note that the builds may already be complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IBuildDetailSpec.Status Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddetailspec.status(v=vs.120).aspx), there is a [BuildStatus Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.buildstatus(v=vs.120).aspx)

The builds status get set to `Inprogress` once started. Then you can monitor the time in the build agent. Reduce the time that you check in the files, you will get what you need.

Comment: The gated check-in builds in question are already complete. They are not in progress. Still I want to know the waiting time for them.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any easy way to do this via TFS API for now if the "waiting time" you mentioned means the time from the build been queued to started.

As you mentioned, your build has already been completed, so you can get the build time information from IBuildDetail, but IBuildDetail only contains IBuildDetail.StartTime and IBuildDetail.FinishTime. The build queue time is include in IQueueBuild (IQueueBuild.Queuetime). So you need to convert IBuildDetail to string and then search the "QueueIds" in the string to get the QueueID. And then you can get IQueueBuild via:

```
IQueuedBuild iqb = IBuildServer.GetQueuedBuild(QueueID,QueryOptions.All);
```

The queue time is iqb.QueueTime. Compare the IQueueBuild.Queuetime with IBuildDetail.StartTime, you should get the waiting time.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the "convert IBuildDetail to string" part. Are you implying there is no API to get the QueueIds? Is this conversion a simple `ToString()` invocation?

Comment: @mark Yes, the QueueID is exist in IBuildDetails but there is no API to get it directly. Convert it to string via ToString(), you will see all the information include in it.

Comment: Unbelievable. I will give it a try.